# Gallery grid overflowing in live server

Tags: html, grid, overflow, gallery, jquery-isotope

I have an HTML document. When I run it in localhost it runs well. But the problem occurs when I run it in live server. the gallery item is overflowing. But the interesting things is when I resize the windows it automatically fixes itself. I have used Magnific popup and Isotope.

[Images that shows in live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lF06.jpg)

here is my html code:

```
<div class="gallery"> 
            <div class="row"> 
                <!-- gallery Image -->
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 gallery-item department doctor patient" href="assets/images/gallery/gallery-3.jpeg"> 
                    <img src="assets/images/gallery/gallery-3.jpeg" alt="" class="gallery-img" />
                </div>
                <!-- gallery Image -->
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 gallery-item doctor department" href="assets/images/gallery/gallery-4.jpeg"> 
                    <img src="assets/images/gallery/gallery-4.jpeg" alt="" class="gallery-img" />
                </div>
                <!-- gallery Image -->
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 gallery-item department" href="assets/images/gallery/gallery-5.jpeg"> 
                    <img src="assets/images/gallery/gallery-5.jpeg" alt="" class="gallery-img" />
                </div>
                <!-- gallery Image -->
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 gallery-item doctor department" href="assets/images/gallery/gallery-6.jpeg"> 
                    <img src="assets/images/gallery/gallery-6.jpeg" alt="" class="gallery-img" />
                </div>
                <!-- gallery Image -->
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 gallery-item surgery department" href="assets/images/gallery/gallery-7.jpeg"> 
                    <img src="assets/images/gallery/gallery-7.jpeg" alt="" class="gallery-img" />
                </div>
                <!-- gallery Image -->
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 gallery-item patient" href="assets/images/gallery/gallery-8.jpeg"> 
                    <img src="assets/images/gallery/gallery-8.jpeg" alt="" class="gallery-img" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 gallery-item doctor" href="assets/images/gallery/gallery-9.jpeg"> 
                    <img src="assets/images/gallery/gallery-9.jpeg" alt="" class="gallery-img" />
                </div>
                <!-- gallery Image -->

            </div> <!-- end .row -->
        </div> <!-- end .gallery -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with how your images are loading. I'm guessing on the live server they are making a call to the server and then being injected into the DOM using JavaScript. [There are a variety of ways](https://css-tricks.com/preventing-content-reflow-from-lazy-loaded-images/) to fix this but the simplest is to add the width and height attributes on your image tags.

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me. I just add a height and it's working fine now